# ComfyUI Manager Error - How can I install tokenziers 0.14 - Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based

Tags: python, pip

I installed ComfyUI-Manager into the custom nodes folder of ComfyUI. I've installed the necessary packages, but I'm encountering an error with the tokenziers, and I can't install version 0.14. When I try to install it using the command "pip install tokenizers==0.14", I still get an error. I'm providing the error messages below.

I clicked run_nvidia_gpu.bat and started cmd.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMC8q.png)

And give me this error

```
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: tokenizers>=0.14,<0.15 is required for a normal functioning of this module, but found tokenizers==0.15.0.
Try: pip install transformers -U or pip install -e '.[dev]' if you're working with git main
```

error image : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO2fL.png)

When I try to install it using the command "pip install tokenizers==0.14", I still get an error.

`

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers
Failed to build tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

error image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8Rvk.png)

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not an image.

Comment: I edited error image. Thank you.